# Does making a View invisible clears memory?

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I have a custom View which I draw on bitmaps in the onDraw function.

if I set View to be invisible through View.setVisibility(View.GONE), it clears all the memory

of the allocated bitmaps?

Comment: Which allocated bitmaps are you referring to?  If you allocated the bitmaps yourself, then they certainly will not be freed by setting this property on the View.  If you are worried about a backbuffer of the View, I'm not sure you can directly control this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. You would have to call `recycle` on the bitmaps to release the memory.

Comment: is there a listener or should I override setVisibility?

Comment: While you could just override setVisibility, that is a bad practice unless you will also automatically handle re-loading the bitmaps if setVisibility is called to make the view visible again.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without knowing your application. If it is unlikely that the view will be re-displayed, then I would say it's probably ok since you won't be reloading the bitmaps over and over.

Comment: I building the inventory screen for my game now. does starting a new activity for this is better than opening the view over the main view?

Comment: It's probably best to use the same view as you're doing (I'm assuming that setting up the view for the game is computationally expensive and that you won't want to do that each time you dismiss the inventory window). What you could do is just make sure you hold onto the bitmaps that will always be displayed (background, etc) and then just load the more dynamic bitmaps each time the inventory view becomes visible.

Comment: just before accepting your answer, if I set the dynamic ones using imageView.setImageDrawable, how can I dismiss the memory they took?

Comment: Keep a reference to the bitmaps and then when you are dine with them, call bitmap.recycle